# Azure AD using ROPC flow for federated account

Tags: azure-active-directory

I would like to ask whether it is possible to use the ROPC flow with Azure Active Directory for an account that is federated via ADFS.

We are successfully authenticating via ROPC using a cloud account, but cannot authenticate using an account via ADFS.

So, I would like to ask if this scenario supported by AAD using the ROPC flow. If yes, is there any specific configuration required on the setup (ADFS / Application) to work?

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD does not support ROPC flow for federated accounts.

Comment: Actually I've heard some people had it working with federated too. But I have no idea what made it work for them. And you really should not use ROPC flow.